# How to check users' cookie in tornado object orientally?

Tags: python, oop, cookies, tornado

I am using tornado web framework with python language.
I want to make a parent class named for example

```
class parentClass(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
def get(self):
    cookie = self.get_cookie("cookie")
```

After that I want to make child classes, such as

```
class childClass(parentClass):
self.write("you have permission")
```

How can I check if the user is permitted to use the website in the parent class? How can I control the child class from the parent class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your usecase is user authentication this is perfectly handled in tornado using the  `@tornado.web.authenticated` decorator on any method with secured access in your handlers.
This will call the `get_current_user` method of the handler which you can implement in the Baseclass (Which would be your ParentClass in your example)

For more info and working code see the excerpt below which I have taken from the according [tornado documentation](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/guide/security.html)

**User authentication**

> The currently authenticated user is available in every request handler
>   as self.current_user, and in every template as current_user. By
>   default, current_user is None.
>
> To implement user authentication in your application, you need to
>   override the get_current_user() method in your request handlers to
>   determine the current user based on, e.g., the value of a cookie. Here
>   is an example that lets users log into the application simply by
>   specifying a nickname, which is then saved in a cookie:

```
class BaseHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get_current_user(self):
        return self.get_secure_cookie("user")

class MainHandler(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        if not self.current_user:
            self.redirect("/login")
            return
        name = tornado.escape.xhtml_escape(self.current_user)
        self.write("Hello, " + name)

class LoginHandler(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.write('<html><body><form action="/login" method="post">'
                   'Name: <input type="text" name="name">'
                   '<input type="submit" value="Sign in">'
                   '</form></body></html>')

    def post(self):
        self.set_secure_cookie("user", self.get_argument("name"))
        self.redirect("/")

application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r"/", MainHandler),
    (r"/login", LoginHandler),
], cookie_secret="__TODO:_GENERATE_YOUR_OWN_RANDOM_VALUE_HERE__")
```

> You can require that the user be logged in using the Python decorator
>   tornado.web.authenticated. If a request goes to a method with this
>   decorator, and the user is not logged in, they will be redirected to
>   login_url (another application setting). The example above could be
>   rewritten:

```
class MainHandler(BaseHandler):
    @tornado.web.authenticated
    def get(self):
        name = tornado.escape.xhtml_escape(self.current_user)
        self.write("Hello, " + name)

settings = {
    "cookie_secret": "__TODO:_GENERATE_YOUR_OWN_RANDOM_VALUE_HERE__",
    "login_url": "/login",
}
application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r"/", MainHandler),
    (r"/login", LoginHandler),
], **settings)
```